# Sending query params as request from Postman

Tags: node.js, express

I'm sending a get request from postman to this url /api/v1/get_services/p but I cannot get the query parameters. The result I get is [object object].

My postman get request looks like this:

```
Postman request: localhost:4000/api/v1/get_services/p?category=Music



Express route:
     apiRoutes.get('/api/v1/get_services/p', async (req, res) => {
      const { category } = req.query;   
      const rootRef = firebase.database().ref(`${category}`);
      await rootRef.once('value', (snap) => {
        if (snap.exists()) {
          console.log(snap.val());
          res.status(200);
          res.send(snap.val());
        } else {
          res.status(404);
          res.send('No services found');
        }
      });
    });
```

Is there any additional configuration that I should add to express middleware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a object builder function to take the correct `req.query`sub elements from the parameter ?

```
function parameterBuilder (body) {

  var record = {}
  record.category = body.category | ' ';
  record.name  = body.name | ' ';
  return record;

}

 apiRoutes.get('/api/v1/get_services/p', async (req, res) => {
  const { category } = req.query; 
     //New code
    var parameters = parameterBuilder(req.query);
    console.log(parameters) // check to see all ur parameters is there
    //end of new code
      const rootRef = firebase.database().ref(`${category}`);
      await rootRef.once('value', (snap) => {
        if (snap.exists()) {
          console.log(snap.val());
          res.status(200);
          res.send(snap.val());
        } else {
          res.status(404);
          res.send('No services found');
        }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request should be:

```
localhost:4000/api/v1/get_services/Music
```

Comment: I want to make it with query like /p?category=Music&name=Apple